# Where to put withRouter in react

Tags: reactjs

In my application, I seperated redux part from the react components. Now i'm confused with, where to put the withRouter(). It works on both component and container, but what will be the good practice?

Here is my code.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'; 
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

import RegisterScreen from './RegisterScreen';
import { registerUser } from '../../../actions';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
   auth: state.auth,
   errors: state.errors
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
   registerUser: bindActionCreators(registerUser, dispatch)
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withRouter(RegisterScreen));
```

Here if we export like, this and set withRouter in the component, still it works. What is the better approach?

```
  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RegisterScreen)
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO it would be cleaner to do it in the component( v.s. its container, if it has one).

That way there can be components that are not connected to the global state(Do not have a container) which still can be wrapped with withRouter if they need its functionality.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only time where it matters is when you want to access the router in `ownProps` in `mapStateToProps`.

You need to wrap the connected component in order to access the router in `mapStateToProps`, like this:

```
export default withRouter(connect(
  mapStateToProps, 
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(RegisterScreen));
```